# Date and format functions

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have a combo box (drop down list) on a user form that lists the current date and the date yesterday. Code below:

```
With currentDate
.AddItem Date
.AddItem Date - 1 
End With
```

As this returns the system date, I'm having trouble formatting it because the macro is used on different computers and they have different system date formats. For some, the date format is "mm/dd/yyyy" e.g. "11/04/2015" and some are system date formats are "dd/mm/yyyy" e.g. "04/11/2015". and I need the combo box to display the "dd/mm/yyyy" even if the system date format is set to "mm/dd/yyyy"

I tried doing this:

```
datefor = Date
datefor = Format(datefor, "dd/mm/yyyy")

With currentDate
.AddItem Date
.AddItem Date - 1
End With
```

But I keep getting an error. Any ideas?

Comment: `Format(Date - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")` This will be a string not a number but should do what you ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to decrease the Date value and then Format.

Try it this way:

```
With currentDate
.AddItem Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
.AddItem Format(Date -1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End With
```

Edited as per Scott's comments.

Comment: Your last line will throw an error, because you are trying to subtract one from a string.

Comment: Tried this without the `Date - 1` and it still didn't work, I mean, i got the error out of the way, but it still displays the system's date format of "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: Let me add on to what I was saying, by declaring datefor as date the math will happen, but depending on the local setting it will subtract either one month or one day.  On mine since I use US settings it subtracts one month, If I was using English settings then yes it would work.  The only method to make sure regardless is to do the math prior to formatting.

Comment: @ScottCraner Aha, that makes more sense, since I am in the UK I didn't notice that.